# JS Highcharts not working

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'll create a "bar" highcharts.([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ngcswa1/1/=))

As you can see in there, my data comes in an array:
`var x = [ [ ["W",20], ["M",9] ] ];.`

If I change the type from bar to pie, my code works fine.

I would like to show one bar - 20% woman, 80% man.

You know what I mean? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Probably this is kind of what you are looking for:

```
series: [{
    name: x[0][0][0],
    data: [x[0][0][1]]
}, {
    name: x[0][1][0],
    data: [x[0][1][1]]
}]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4ngcswa1/5/

But it is a good idea to change the data format to better match what chart expects .

Comment: how should it looks like?

Comment: did you check my fiddle? it will display the result

Comment: sorry: "But it is a good idea to change the data format to better match what chart expects" 
It's better to change the data forma :) how?

Comment: Basically server-side or source for the chart should produce output similar to what azibi already proposed: [{
        name: 'M',
        data: [80]
    }, {
        name: 'F',
        data: [20]
    }]

Answer (score 0):

You need one object in the series array for every element in the chart

```
    series: [{
        name: 'M',
        data: [80]
    }, {
        name: 'F',
        data: [20]
    }]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ngazy8a2/

Comment: problem is that I use series also for type "pie".. so I need my snippet

Comment: I am not sure if you can use the same data object for both graphs 'as is' I think you need to treat each data different for every type of graph